# Unable to put an annotation on ng-2charts line chart

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I am using [ng2-chart](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#/LineChart) to create charts in Angular 8.

I have only one problem: I am not able to set an annotation on my chart.

The x axis of the chart are dates (as strings) with the following format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.z`

The annotation configuration is the following:

```
let annotation = {
                drawTime: 'afterDraw', // tried default afterDatasetsDraw without success
                type: 'line',
                mode: 'vertical',
                scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
                value: deviceInjectionTime, // This value is also a `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.z` string date
                borderColor: 'orange',
                borderWidth: 2,
                label: {
                  enabled: true,
                  fontColor: 'orange',
                  content: 'DEVICE'
                }
              };
          this.lineChartOptionsITAG.annotation.annotations.push(annotation);
```

My chart options are:

```
 public lineChartOptionsITAG: (ChartOptions & { annotation: any }) = {
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
      // We use this empty structure as a placeholder for dynamic theming.
      xAxes: [{}],
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: 'y-axis-0',
          position: 'left',
          gridLines: {
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.3)',
          },
        },
      ]
    },
    annotation: {
      annotations: [

      ],
    },
  };
```

The current result is the following:

[image: current]

The desired result is the following:
[image: desired]

Is what I am trying possible ? If so, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: _The red line on the image is where SHOULD be the vertical line_ - could you please clarify? The red line is already vertical.

Comment: @MichaelD Yes. I made it myself on the screenshot. This is where it should be if it worked. (updated question)

Comment: Then it would be helpful to reformat the question to show the actual output image below _The current result is the following_ and the manually edited image under _Expected result_.